# Get combination of sublists with length n

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Say I have a list `lst = [[[24, 25], [25, 26], [25, 35]], [[24, 25, 26], [26, 36, 46]]]`.
I want to calculate all combinations with all elements from other sublists, but **not** the same sublist. In this example it would be:

```py
[[24, 25], [24, 25, 26]],
[[25, 26], [24, 25, 26]],
[[25, 35], [24, 25, 26]],
[[24, 25], [26, 36, 46]],
[[25, 26], [26, 36, 46]],
[[25, 35], [26, 36, 46]]
```

This should however also be able to produce combinations of more than 2 elements, i.e. `lst = [[[1]], [[2], [3]], [[4], [5]]]; (length=len(lst) -> 3)`:

```py
[[1], [2], [4]],
[[1], [2], [5]],
[[1], [3], [4]],
[[1], [3], [5]]
```

I tried with `itertools.combinations(*lst)` but that only netted tuples of length 2.
How can I achieve combinations of length **n** with the limitations outlined above?

Comment: I think you want itertools.product

Comment: That might indeed be correct. Want to make it an answer?

Comment: You can mark the one from @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the cartesian product over two or more iterables:

```py
from itertools import product

top = [[[24, 25], [25, 26], [25, 35]], [[24, 25, 26], [26, 36, 46]]]

for combo in product(*top):
  print(combo)
```

Outputs:

```
([24, 25], [24, 25, 26])
([24, 25], [26, 36, 46])
([25, 26], [24, 25, 26])
([25, 26], [26, 36, 46])
([25, 35], [24, 25, 26])
([25, 35], [26, 36, 46])
```